# Stored procedure to update records extremely slow input is done through C#

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I've got a SQL Server database with 2,5 million records and I need to update the records. The source is a C# program which uses a stored procedure. After checking, the stored procedure takes a long time for updating.

When I use a transaction, a 1000 records takes about 10 minutes. I've put index keys on all the columns which are used for search or if there is a condition on the columns, this did not help to speed up.

The unique identifier is a string and can't be a changed to a numeric value. The value of the other columns are changable. I think my the cause of the slowdown is in the following section

```
FROM 
    [Policy] 
WHERE
    [UniqueIdentifier] = @UniqueIdentifier
    AND ([ParentIdentifierId] != @ParentIdentifierId
         OR [PolId] != @PolId
         OR [ClaimNumber] != @ClaimNumber
         OR [ClaimStatus] != @ClaimStatus
         OR [Description] != @Description))
```

I've stripped the stored procedure of the columns which only do an update and don't have any other function. The total number of columns is 30.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_WriteDatatoolUpdate_test01] 
    @Dossier VARCHAR(50),
    @ParentIdentifierId VARCHAR(50),
    @PolId VARCHAR(50),
    @ClaimNumber VARCHAR(50),
    @ClaimStatus VARCHAR(50),
    @Description VARCHAR(255),
    @RecordExtractionDate VARCHAR(50),
    @UniqueIdentifier VARCHAR(50),
    @RecordCreationDate DATE = NULL,
    @UpDate DATE = NULL,
    @ChangedAfterUpdate VARCHAR(1),
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [Policy] 
                  WHERE [UniqueIdentifier] = @UniqueIdentifier)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [Policy] ([Dossier], [ParentIdentifierId], [PolId],
                              [ClaimNumber], [ClaimStatus], [Description],
                              [RecordExtractionDate], [UniqueIdentifier], 
                              [RecordCreationDate],[UpDate],[ChangedAfterUpdate]
        VALUES (@Dossier, @ParentIdentifierId, @PolId,
                @ClaimNumber, @ClaimStatus, @Description,
                @RecordExtractionDate, @UniqueIdentifier,
                @RecordCreationDate, @UpDate, @ChangedAfterUpdate 
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                  -- probable cause of the slowdown
                  -- Need to select1 and check if needed to update
                  FROM [Policy] 
                  WHERE [UniqueIdentifier] = @UniqueIdentifier
                    AND ([ParentIdentifierId] != @ParentIdentifierId
                         OR [PolId] != @PolId
                         OR [ClaimNumber] != @ClaimNumber
                         OR [ClaimStatus] != @ClaimStatus
                         OR [Description] != @Description))
                -- here are some more fields to check,
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [Policy] 
            SET [ParentIdentifierId] = @ParentIdentifierId,
                [PolId] = @PolId,
                [ClaimNumber] = @ClaimNumber,
                [ClaimStatus] = @ClaimStatus,
                [Description] = @Description,
                [UpDate] = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()),
                [ChangedAfterUpdate ] = 'Y'
            WHERE [UniqueIdentifier] = @UniqueIdentifier
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [Policy] 
            SET [UpDate] = CONVERT(date,GETDATE()),
                [ChangedAfterUpdate ] = 'N'
            WHERE [UniqueIdentifier] = @UniqueIdentifier
        END
    END
END
```

Comment: Any reason you are updating the records one by one instead of in a batch using a table valued parameter? (one such reason would be if you have some records that might raise an error but you do want other records to be inserted/updated anyway)

Comment: You can use a WHERE clause in INSERT and UPDATE queries, which will reduce both your code *and* the time it needs to execute in half, if not less. You *don't* need to an *shouldn't*  update one row at a time. You end up paying the network roundtrip N times instead of once. The result is that for 1000 rows you end up with *at least* 1000 slower performance

Comment: The UPDATE branch updates the *SAME* row with the same values. What's the point of performing *another* `EXISTS` call, which wasn't needed to begin with? Just update the row in a single UPDATE. There's no harm done if the query sets the same value to a field that it already has. You can use a CASE WHEN clause to store a different value to `ChangedAfterUpdate`, although even that isn't needed.

Comment: You can use Change Tracking in all SQL Server versions and editions to find out which rows have changed since a specific version number. You don't need to use extra fields for this

Answer (score 0):

Column amount in update (10 vs 30) has not significant effect on performance. In your case, problem might be where-condition as you have suspected. Here are some strategies to try:

**Isolate slow queries:**
Isolate slow part of your query with Sql Server tools: [Query plan
    visualizer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071(v=sql.105).aspx) and/or [SQL profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler). In your case slow part can be query's where-clause containing multiple OR-conditions.

**Optimize slow queries**
Optimize slow queries by modifying indices and/or refactoring it to separate sub-queries if possible.

**Use bulk operations when possible**
If possible, use bulk operations and avoid massive amount one-by-one sql-transactions. If using [.NET BulkCopy insertions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) it may need some extra temp tables and merge operations.  Bulk update can be implemented i.e with following tools:

- By using [external library](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Extensions) which is specialized on high-speed Bulk operations
- By crafting sql stored procedure which takes array of data as parameter. More information about table-valued parameters can be found in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine

Comment: Thanks, I will look at this.